# What is the canonical way of overloading string conversion in swift?

Tags: debugging, swift, struct, output

**QUESTION**

Suppose I have a struct like this:

```
struct Foo
{
  var i : Int
  var c : Character
}
```

*What is the canonical way of providing output to NSLog() for debugging purposes?*

In other words, is there a C++ equivalent of `friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, Foo const& foo )` in swift that I should implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `Printable` protocol.

```
struct Foo: Printable {
    var i : Int
    var c : Character

    var description: String {
        return "i = \(self.i), c = \(self.c)"
    }
}

var foo = Foo(i: 1, c: "a")
println(foo)
println("foo = \(foo)")
NSLog("\(foo)")
```

Also implement `DebugPrintable` for separate description specially for debug if necessary:

```
protocol DebugPrintable {
    var debugDescription: String { get }
}
```